# Splunk rex expression to remove comma if present in json file

Tags: regex, sed, splunk, rex

I have stuck in a small issue where I need to remove last character "," ( if present) from JSON log file. I am using it in Splunk.

It seems simple and I was hoping my regex will work but its not working.
My Attempts :

```
1. s/\(,$\)?//g
2. s/,$//g
3. s/\(.*\),/\1/
```

FYI: My json file is nested, along with removing last character, I am removing some header and footers from this file and breaking the 1 event in multiple. Due to event break it has , at the end of each event.
For better understanding can refer this link which I posted on Splunk Community fourm
https://community.splunk.com/t5/Getting-Data-In/Updated-Help-in-event-break-for-json-file/td-p/569676

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually there was an extra space at the end so below one is working but it cause another issue.

`Working Regex s/\(,\s$\)//g`

because I am using it with other regex and event break. Not event break is not working.

Other Regex

```
SEDCMD-removefooter = s/(\]\,).*//g
SEDCMD-removeheader = s/\{\"data\": \[//g
LINE_BREAKER = ([\r\n,]*(?:{[^[{]+\[)?){"links"
```

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: yes finally...

SEDCMD-replacequotes = s/'/"/g
SEDCMD-removecomma = s/,\s$//g
SEDCMD-removefooter = s/(\]\,).*//g
SEDCMD-removeheader = s/\{.data.: \[//g

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue

Working regex

```
SEDCMD-replacequotes = s/'/"/g
SEDCMD-removecomma = s/,\s$//g
SEDCMD-removefooter = s/(\]\,).*//g
SEDCMD-removeheader = s/\{.data.: \[//g
```

Comment: don't give multiple answers to your question, edit an answer you give to be complete :)